# Update record by adding a value to an existing value in file and show updated value

Tags: c, file, append

I'm new to programming. I'm trying to create a program that when you input an amount of money it is saved in a file and when entering a new value it adds the new value with the existing value in the file. After adding the values, it needs to show the total amount of saved money.

Code for inputting money and saving to file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void total();

int main(){
 double dSavings;
 FILE *fptr;
 do {
     fptr = fopen("store.txt","a");
     if (fptr == NULL){
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter money you want to save:");
    scanf("%lf",&dSavings);
 } while(dSavings <= 0);
    fprintf(fptr,"Amount saved today is %1.2f\n",dSavings);
    fclose(fptr);
    total();
}
```

Code for showing total amount of money saved

```
void total(){
 FILE *fptr;
 double dSavings;
 if ((fptr = fopen("store.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error! opening file");
    exit(1);
 }
  fscanf(fptr, "%lf", &dSavings);
  printf("Total savings: %1.2f\n",dSavings);
  fclose(fptr);
}
```

When I compile and run it, it doesn't show the stored values. [image]

Comment: Seems like the `fopen` should either be before or after the do-while loop, not inside the loop.

Comment: In your `total` function, you probably want `fscanf(fptr, "Amount saved today is %lf", &dSavings);` to correctly extract the number on the line. Also, I assume you want to add all the savings together - in which case, you'd need to wrap this in a loop to add up the savings in the file.